# How to block Permissions asked by an android app with fake data

Tags: android, permissions, block, shadow

I am trying to control permission grant based on user choice. So if say user walks out in public and doesn't want to share his/her location with facebook app, he/she should revoke that pemission grant and system should send some fake data to facebook. Android 4.3 have this feature with permission manager, but it doesn't send fake data, rather block permission altogether rendering app not work at all.

Comment: This is not possible, except by building your own custom version of Android and roll it into your own ROM mod. Furthermore, you are completely wrong in your interpretation of Android 4.3's "App Ops" behaves, as it will offer fake empty data as needed: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/07/26/app-ops-developer-faq.html

Comment: Is there a way i can modify App Ops. When i downloaded its APK, it showed mere invocation of AppOpsSummary component and injecting it in new intent. How can i customize its category and other features.

Comment: "Is there a way i can modify App Ops" -- since it is part of the open source repository, presumably one could modify it. I have not tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [XPrivacyLua](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacyLua). Requires ROOT, though.